# C# Managed Add-in Framework with Event-driven Architecture

Tags: c#, plugins, architecture, maf

Is there any way to use an event-driven architecture with the .NET 3.5 managed add-in framework?

From what I can see, MAF only allows direct pre-defined function calls with a strictly defined data pipeline for information exchange between the host and plugins. I'm looking for a framework that allows for hot-swappable plugins in an application while still allowing for an event-driven architecture (from both the host and plugin sides).

If MAF cannot do this, is there any framework that can?

Comment: Those pre-defined function calls could be to interfaces whose instances are loaded through MAF.  There's also MEF, which is a more recent version of an "add-in" framework (extension framework).

Comment: Thanks for the input! I ended up re-architecting the entire application to avoid using MAF altogether, as upon further reflection, it was unnecessary. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up moving away from MAF entirely, as drag-and-drop functionality was unnecessary.